# Do the Chris Nolan Batman movies have a unique Gotham accent?

Tags: dialogue, the-dark-knight-rises, the-dark-knight, batman-begins

I cannot place American accents particularly well, so this is not intuitive to me based on watching the Christopher Nolan Batman movies.

Do the cast use a particular accent to place themselves in the (fictional) Gotham City? Certainly Gary Oldman, who is from London, England, would have to deliberately affect an accent of one kind or another. Is there any evidence that a particular accent was chosen or synthesised to represent Gotham? Would this be obvious to U.S. natives where Gotham is supposed to be?

Comment: Why do you think they needed accent for gotham citizens?

Comment: There is no specific accent, except for ‘dark and brooding’ in the Chris Nolan movies. Gotham is located in New Jersey with with new england influences.

Comment: That could have been great (see what they did with the language/accent in Black Panther) but probably too much work. Also, Gotham is basically a dark version of New York, so it is supposed to be a cosmopolitan city.

Comment: @Vishwa that's the question I'm asking.

Comment: The only thing always mentioned is that Gary Oldman had to learn an "American Accent" and did it so well, he forgot his own english accent and had to learn it again after the movie. I have never seen any specific accent mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any specific references from the actors about how they chose their accents, but it definitely sounds to me like it's supposed to be somewhere between a New York and Chicago accent (so, broadly Northeastern American). I think that it's easiest to see this in the [Joker Mob Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3oOldViIgY) and [when Dent and Gordon are talking to Batman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltC68UY7UX0).

Generally, New York accents have [more raised and tense vowels](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/426207#Vowels) and is non-rhotic (dropping r's in the middle and end of words). You see this most with the mob bosses and a bit with Harvey Dent. Chicago/Inland Northern Accents also have more [raised](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/3173913#Phonetics) vowels, but they tend to extend them a bit more and make them [diphthongs](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/270794). I think Gary Oldman is doing more of a Chicago accent. The Joker kind of blends them together, which definitely makes conveys how he's a more chaotic figure than many of the other characters.